# $\zeta(0)$ of lichnerowicz operator on sphere quotients

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, zeta-functions

Consider the lichnerowicz operator acting on symmetric traceless tensors on an even sphere $S^d$ with conical defect parametrized by angular deficit $\alpha$. Is there a simple way to understand/predict the $\alpha$ dependence of the spectral $\zeta_\alpha(0)$ ? There are general Polyakov formulas for conformal transformation of $\zeta_\alpha'(z)$ in $z=0$, but $\zeta_\alpha(0)$ in this restricted case should be simple(r) although varying $\alpha$ is not conformal.